# ssh log - a particular ip-address has only connection closed message

Tags: security, ssh

It is strange, but I was going through logs at /var/log/secure (CentOS 6.2). As such it is typical for break-in attempts to be logged. However, there is one such record:

```
Connection closed by 76.XX.XX.X
```

But no corresponding 'Failed' or 'Accepted' log records. Is this a case of successful break-in where the intruder erased the log records and only the post disconnect log remain? How do I go about analyzing the situation? I have configured iptables to allow only 2 attempts per minute for SSH. 'root' login is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

That just means that 76.xx.xx.x opened a tcp connection to ssh port and then closed it without trying to authenticate.